# Function being used, when it isn't a function?

Tags: javascript

```
Battle.CreateInputs = function(json) {
if (json.Battle.Continue !== undefined) {
    $('#attackBox').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Continue').mousedown(function(e) {
        Battle.PlaySound('die')
        Battle.Continue($(this).attr('continue'), e);
        return false;
    });
} else if (json.Battle.Captcha !== undefined) {
    $('#attackBox').css('display', 'none');
    $('#CaptchaForm').submit(function(e) {
        Battle.PlaySound('captcha')
        Battle.SubmitCaptcha($('#Captcha').val(), e);
        return false;
    });
} else if (json.Battle.Restart !== undefined) {        
    $('#attackBox').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Restart').click(function(e) {
        Battle.PlaySound('coin')
        Battle.Restart($(this).attr('restart'), e);
        return false;
    });
} else {
    $('#attackBox').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('input').mousedown(function(e) {
        Battle.PlaySound('hit')
        Battle.Move($(this).attr('post_code'), e);
        return false;
    });
}};
```

So, this is the code that I'm having problems with. I always receive the error "Battle.PlaySound is not a function". Here is a link to the Javascript and the code snippet that I was using.

My Code - http://pastebin.com/BnHLaYN3

Site Javascript - http://pastebin.com/0NcyWvGn

Comment: What is `PlaySound()` if not a function?...You're defining it as an empty object `{}`...but it sure looks like you're calling it as a function.

Comment: I simply tried making it a function to go along with the error that I was getting. As it stands, I can just edit the serverside Javascript, so I tried to add it as a function in my snippet to see if it'd work at all, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

`Battle.PlaySound` is indeed not a function. As per your code:

```
Battle.PlaySound = {};
```

You are defining it as an object.

Should be something like this instead:

```
Battle.PlaySound = function(sound) {
    //Do something with sound here.
};
```

Comment: Gave what a try? That's your actual code. As per it is now, you will never be able to call Battle.PlaySound as a function.

Comment: I edited my previous comment since I misunderstood what you had said.

Comment: Ok. The only thing I can think of is to redefine Battle.PlaySound as a function.

Comment: Not quite sure what would go in the function, is the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're not sure what you want to do...What are you trying to do with `PlaySound`?

Comment: With the code from that link you will get a maximum stack size exceeded error for sure.

Comment: Oh, I see. Hmm.. Not quite sure then, though I wasn't sure if it'd work anyways..